# How to create and push my docker image to dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have the following folder structure:

```
--project
 --front
    --Dockerfile (dockerfile_front)
 --back
    --Dockerfile (dockerfile_back)

 Dockerfile (dockerfile_root)
 compose.yaml
```

The contents are:

dockerfile_front:

```
    FROM node:latest
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 3000
    RUN npm install -g serve
    CMD ["serve"]
```

dockerfile_back:

```
    FROM node:latest
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install
    RUN npx prisma generate
    CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

dockerfile_root:

```
    FROM docker/compose:latest
    COPY compose.yaml /game-app
    WORKDIR /game-app
    CMD ["docker-compose", "up", "-d"]
```

compose.yaml

```
  version: "3"
  services:
    db:
      image: mysql:8.0
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: games
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      volumes:
        - ./back/prisma/seed:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    api:
      build:
        context: ./back
      ports:
        - 3001:3001
      depends_on:
        - db
      restart: always
      environment:
        DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:root@db:3306/games
        JWT_SECRET: 1234567899oiuywrifasdfdufbdsfldsv
      volumes:
        - ./back:/app

    web:
      build:
        context: ./front
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
      depends_on:
        - api
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./front:/app
```

So the question is:
I want to push this to hub for some friends just pull this image and they already get all the directories with files etc.
How can i do that? I was trying run the command:  `docker build -t hramos13/game-project:latest .` on my root directory but getting errors like:

```
Dockerfile:8
8 | >>> WORKDIR /game-app
ERROR: failed to solve: mkdir 
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/x0j75xyx522ge5fum80wcbfty/merged/game-app: not a directory
```

Its my first day using docker and i really dont know even if on the Dockerfile_root i should put this image `FROM docker/compose:latest` or another.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point here is probably to figure out what your colleagues will run.  Since they will not have the source code locally, they can't `build:` images, and they can't inject the content with `volumes:`.  On the other hand, they do need to know the name of the Docker Hub `image:` for each of the involved containers.  They will need to see

```yaml
services:
  db: { ... }
  api:
    image: hramos13/game-api:${TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:root@db:3306/games
      JWT_SECRET: 1234567899oiuywrifasdfdufbdsfldsv
```

Your local repository can also have a `docker-compose.override.yaml`, and [Compose will merge them together](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/).  This is a good place to put build settings.

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build: ./back

  web:
    build: ./front
```

With both of these files, you can `docker-compose build` the two images, then `docker-compose push` them.

Your colleague will need the `docker-compose.yaml` file and the `./back/prisma/seed` directory, but none of the rest of the local source tree.  They just need to run `docker-compose up` and Compose will take care of downloading the images.

I'd delete the `dockerfile_root` entirely.  In principle, yes, it would encapsulate the Compose tool and the Compose file, but running it is complicated and it needs a lot of power over the host system.  It's reasonable to expect anyone who can install Docker to also install Compose as an all-but-standard tool.  Your colleagues will need the Compose file to run the project but shouldn't need any of the other source.